# Rails: gem file/ bundle install with gem 'bootstrap-sass'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

**I added the line to the gem file:**

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'        '3.3.2.0'
```

**then I got:**

```
$ bundle install 
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........... 
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/.. 
Resolving dependencies... 
Could not find gem 'bootstrap-sass3.3.2.0 (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

**so I downloaded and installed it from rubygems.org:**

```
$ gem install bootstrap-sass -v 3.3.2.0
Fetching: autoprefixer-rails-5.1.11.gem (100%)
Successfully installed autoprefixer-rails-5.1.11
Fetching: bootstrap-sass-3.3.2.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bootstrap-sass-3.3.2.0
2 gems installed
```

**Then tried:**

```
$bundle install
or/and
$bundle update
```

**And still getting the message:**

```
Could not find gem 'bootstrap-sass3.3.2.0 (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

**What should I do?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are installing any gem  with perticular version you should have to give a comma in between gem and version (or any other parameter its optional).
like,

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass','3.3.2.0'
```

but if you want to install only gem without any version you need to give only gem file name,that enough

like,

```
 gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

The benefit of above declaring gem is that it's version independent,because bundle installer will automatically download latest version gem, for our project.

In the below code you can see that i used Rails with 4.2.1 version and i separated with it comma, but for further gems I did not mentioned any version.
so bundle installer will automatically install latest version for you are Rails project.

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
```

Answer (score 5):

You forgot the comma between gem name, and version.

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.2.0'
```

Refer to the [documentation](http://bundler.io/man/gemfile.5.html), you need to specify your optional parameters separated by `,`.